# Increase table rows height of a single table

Tags: tables, height

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
$\displaystyle \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I would like to make the row height larger so that $f(n)$ does not touch the upper horizontal line. Additional requirement is that I would like to omit using fancy packages and I want that only one particular table is affected.

Comment: maybe try this:

\hline
\vspace{6pt}

$\displaystyle ... $ \\
\vspace{6pt}

\hline

(a line of whitespace is needed below each vspace)

Comment: note article does not have a 14pt option (your example file warns about that)

Comment: @Nate vspace in a `c` column will do nothing useful

Comment: what do you count as a "fancy" pckage? `array` for example should almost always be used for tables, and `amsmath` should almost always be used for math. `array` would help here. Both are part of the core latex distribution, and so as fundamental as `article` class which you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define a `\tabdfrac` command that takes the arguments as `\frac`, but also an optional argument for the separation (default 3pt).

The idea is to typeset `\dfrac` in a box and increase both the height and depth thereof by the specified separation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tabdfrac}[3][3pt]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\dfrac{#2}{#3}$}%
  \increase@dfrac\ht{#1}%
  \increase@dfrac\dp{#1}%
  \box\z@
}
\newcommand{\increase@dfrac}[2]{%
  \dimen@=#1\z@ \advance\dimen@ #2
  #1\z@=\dimen@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
$\tabdfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
$\tabdfrac[6pt]{f(n)}{g(n)}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have increased the table rows height of a single table. I have added `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}` before tabular and I have increased further
the row with `\\[1em]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline 
$\displaystyle \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ \\[1em]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```